# Using ref getter function returns undefined

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm still trying to work through [this tutorial](http://miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-3/), but with mixed success. In my controller script, I have the following:

```
config: {
        refs: {
            notesListContainer: 'noteslistcontainer',
            noteEditor: 'noteeditor'
        },
        control: {
            notesListContainer: {
                newNoteCommand: 'onNewNoteCommand',
                editNoteCommand: 'onEditNoteCommand'
            }
        }
},
onEditNoteCommand: function(list, record) {
    console.log('onEditNoteCommand');

    this.activateNoteEditor(record);
},
activateNoteEditor: function(record) {
        var noteEditor = this.getNoteEditor();
        noteEditor.setRecord(record);
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(noteEditor, this.slideLeftTransition);
},
```

When I run this in Chromium 18.0.1025.168, I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setRecord' of undefined Notes.js:37`. 
`this.getNoteEditor()'
```

does not return the noteEditor, but returns undefined.

The entire project's source is available [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?1ml1lumkafeh8zl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The important thing is to specify the ref as autoCreated using `autoCreate : true`

```
config: {
    refs: {
        notesListContainer: 'noteslistcontainer',
        noteEditor: {
                 selector: 'noteeditor',
                 xtype: 'noteeditor',
                 autoCreate: true // missing
            }
        },
    },
...
}
```

Comment: After adding that line of code to the refs, I still get same error.

Comment: was too eager and make a mistake in the syntax. Main idea is to define the form as autoCreated